# Create something like InputDecoration and OutlineInputBorder for Text Widget

Tags: flutter, text, flutter-layout, textfield

I would like to implement a Text Widget whose label works in a similar way to the TextField below. (I don't expect I can input a value to the Text Widget. The Text Widget will be only for showing a text.) Could anyone teach me this?

- If the value is '' (empty string), then show "Output" in the box.
- If the value is not empty, then show "Output" on the border.

***TextField sample***

Without value:

[image: Without value]

With value:

[image: With value]

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Input',
    labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
    errorText: _hasInputError ? 'Invalid number entered' : null,
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  TextFormField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Input',
                hintText: "Input",
                labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                errorText: _hasInputError ? 'Invalid number entered' : null,
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer.I'm sorry but I guess I made you confused due to my bad writing. I updated the question. Could you check it?

Comment: To be honest question is not 100% clear to me. The answer will work as the provided images. 
Please let me know if you want to change the text from the code? because you mentioned you don't want enter something, if I am right?

Comment: you mentioned you don't want enter something --> You are right. And... I think the main point is I want to use `Text Widget`.

Comment: You can insert text using TextEditingController through code https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html